# Venmo Android integration multiple recipients

Tags: android, venmo

I am trying to use the Venmo Android SDK but am running into an issue when I try and send a charge to multiple users. If i use this:

```
https://venmo.com/?txn=charge&amount=23.25&note=for+dinner&recipients=hamilton@venmo.com,646.863.9557,john
```

in my computers web browser it pulls up the venmo site with three people that will split the charge, However if I try something like that in my android app it will only take the first recipient.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Just got confirmation from Venmo that this is currently not possible.

Comment: It's fine to answer your own question, I'd suggest you post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venmo Confirmed that this is currently not possible in the android sdk.